# C Makefile gives linker errors with multiple definitions

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

I have the following makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
HWK = /c/cs323/Hwk2/
objects = code1.o lzw.o

lzw: encode
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o lzw encode

encode: decode
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o encode decode

decode: lzw.o
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o decode lzw.o


lzw.o: lzw.c ${HWK}code1.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c lzw.c ${HWK}code1.c
```

When I try to run "make lzw", I get the following errors:

```
decode: In function `_fini':
(.fini+0x0): multiple definition of `_fini'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.fini+0x0): first defined here
decode: In function `data_start':
(.data+0x0): multiple definition of `__data_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.data+0x0): first defined here
decode:(.rodata+0x8): multiple definition of `__dso_handle'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/crtbegin.o:(.rodata+0x0): first defined here
decode:(.rodata+0x0): multiple definition of `_IO_stdin_used'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.rodata.cst4+0x0): first defined here
decode: In function `_start':
(.text+0x0): multiple definition of `_start'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crt1.o:(.text+0x0): first defined here
decode: In function `_init':
(.init+0x0): multiple definition of `_init'
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/../../../../lib64/crti.o:(.init+0x0): first defined here
/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/4.8.2/crtend.o:(.tm_clone_table+0x0): multiple definition of `__TMC_END__'
decode:(.data+0x8): first defined here
/usr/bin/ld: error in decode(.eh_frame); no .eh_frame_hdr table will be created.
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I've found some places online with similar errors, but none of them seem to apply (e.g., I don't have to mains in my program). What's wrong?

Comment: It's not clear what your source files are, nor how many programs you're trying to build, and (in part because of that) it's not clear which files are needed to build which programs. Superficially, you have two source files, `lzw.c` and `code1.c`, with the second not located in the current directory. Superficially, you are trying to create 3 programs: `lzw`, `encode` and `decode`. The rule to build `decode` is sane if the only object file required is `lzw.o`. The rule to build `encode` is insane; you try to run the linker using a complete program, `decode` as the only object file. I'm confused!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seems like you compile your files multiple times. Try this:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall
HWK = /c/cs323/Hwk2/
objects = code1.o lzw.o

lzw: encode.o

encode.o: decode.o
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o encode.c

decode.o: lzw.o
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -o decode.c


lzw.o: lzw.c ${HWK}code1.c
    ${CC} ${CFLAGS} -c lzw.c ${HWK}code1.c
```

Notice that you don't need to (and in this case shouldn't!) build dependencies of a file in the same command line. Marking the dependencies with a colon is enough, make will do the work for you.

Comment: That seemed to fix that, but with that makefile I'm getting the error "gcc -g3 -std=c99 -pedantic -Wall -o encode          \          
gcc: fatal error: no input files". I'm guessing that's outside the scope of this question, so thanks for the help.

Comment: This means that a file named encode does not exist. You need to pass a file to gcc, maybe you meant encode.c? Updated the code in the answer, try now. Should work, assuming the filenames are correct.

Comment: What I want is for lzw, encode, and decode to all be executables, while lzw.c and ${HWK}code1.c are the only actual c files being used.

Comment: Why do the executables depend on each other then?

Comment: This isn't right, at all.  `encode.o` depends on `decode.o`, and the compilation outputs its results to `encode.c`...?!?!  Why did you accept this answer?